# Packing GUI widgets in Python? (MAC)

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I am very new to Python and learning about GUI programs.
Two things:

1. I would like the questions to show up as a list (the second question and its answer box directly under the first), but I am not sure of all the positioning functions.
2. Also, I would like to change the name at top of the window to say MPG Calculator (currently it says "tk").

Here is the code (below) and output photo that deals with this part of the program

[image]

```
import tkinter

from tkinter import messagebox

class milesPerGallon:

    def __init__(self):

        # Make main window
        self.main_window = tkinter.Tk()

        # make frames
        self.top_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.bottom_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)

        # Make top widgets using .top_frame function
        self.prompt_label = tkinter.Label(self.top_frame, \
                                          text='How many gallons does the car hold? ')
        self.gallons_entry = tkinter.Entry(self.top_frame, \
                                        width=10)

        self.prompt_label2 = tkinter.Label(self.top_frame, \
                                          text='\nIn miles, how far can it go on a full tank? ')
        self.miles_entry = tkinter.Entry(self.top_frame, \
                                        width=10)

        # Pack top widgets
        self.prompt_label.pack(side='left')
        self.gallons_entry.pack(side='left')
        self.prompt_label2.pack(side='left')
        self.miles_entry.pack(side='left')

        # Make bottom wigdets using .bottom_frame function
        self.calc_button = tkinter.Button(self.bottom_frame, \
                                          text='Calculate', \
                                          command=self.convert)
        self.quit_button = tkinter.Button(self.bottom_frame, \
                                          text='Quit', \
                                          command=self.main_window.destroy)
        # Pack buttons
        self.calc_button.pack(side='left')
        self.quit_button.pack(side='left')

        # Pack frames
        self.top_frame.pack()
        self.bottom_frame.pack()

        # Call Tkinter main loop.
        tkinter.mainloop()
```

Thanks for checking out my question; I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
self.main_window.title("MPG Calculator")
```

by adding the `.title` command you can change the name of a page.

I couldn't test your GUI so perhaps its a different page that has to be changed but it works via the same principe.

since I couldn't test your GUI I haven't got a solution for your other problem.